# Intellij New Json Scratch file

Tags: intellij-idea

ctrl+shift+N shows the dialog to choose new scratch files type. It didn't before, I'm very confused. On what does this depend on?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what caused your IDE to get that configuration, but you can easily revert it by going to:

**File** > **Settings...** > **Keymap** and set back their default values.

- Reset the new Scratch File option

  1. Search for word "scratch" in order to find it faster.
  2. Set its value back to (default) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

[image]

- Reset the Navigate to File option

  1. Select "Navigation" > "File".
  2. Set its value back to (default) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Also, make sure your keymap doesn't clash with your OS, which might produce some unexpected results. Here are a very good articles about it:

- [Mastering IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcuts (by Jetbrains)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html)
- [Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)
- [Mastering IntelliJ IDEA Keyboard Shortcuts (by Medium)](https://medium.com/@andrey_cheptsov/mastering-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-62e95883dcc5)